# How to display a RDLC report to SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, visual-studio, reports

I have created an `RDLC` report with visual studio and it looks like this:

[image]

But the problem is that I don't know how to publish it in SharePoint page.
So how can I display this report to SharePoint `Home.aspx` page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily render your `RDLC` report in `Report viewer control` within a `visual web part` using visual studio then publish it to your SharePoint.

> **Note:**
>
> You may face issue related to the compatibility between the Report
>   viewer version in your web part and your Sharepoint config, so make
>   sure that both versions are identical as mentioned at
>   [(Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer) is not compatible with 
>   the type of control (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/04/21/the-base-class-includes-the-field-xxx-but-its-type-microsoft-reporting-webforms-reportviewer-is-not-compatible-with-the-type-of-control-microsoft-reporting-webforms-reportviewer/)

---

By the way, You have mentioned in tags, you are using  Sharepoint Enterprise, So Why you didn't use **Reporting Service integrated mode**,

- It helps you to build and publish your reports easily using Report builder or visual studio,
- You will be able to host it in `Report Viewer Web Part`.